# Where does Java look for files when using StdIn interface from Command Line?

Tags: java, cmd, stdin

I'm having a small embarrassing issue. I'm forgetting where Java looks for command-line files. For example if I am running the following from windows command line prompt:
    java -cp "C:\Path\To\class\" ClassName input.txt

Where does Java think I am asking it to look for input.txt? As of right now it doesn't seem to find the file if the file is anywhere in the system's PATH, or the java CLASS PATH.

This is a really stupid issue and I've spent over an hour on it and I can't seem to come to a conclusion. The worst part was that I've resolved this issue before but am having a bad day trying to remember how.

NOTE: This is not the same as the question "Where does java look for a file" when you are using a scanner from inside the program. This is specific to the method that looks like

```
public class Classname {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: Hi, I resolved the problem. I was a getting a "NoClassDeffFound" error and it had to do with my Class path. My solution was to add a temporary class path location of the current directory by saying
    set classpath=%classpath%;.;

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how almost anything works with paths, if it's a relative path, it's based from your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a weird issue where if I move up to "C:\Path\To\class\" and run the command from there, it won't find input.txt and I get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: Well, is that where input.txt is?

Comment: Yeah, input file is the path I used for ClassPath. And it throws a
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I try to reference it.

If I comment out the code or leave the filename blank (Aka, my parser skips the input file part) I get no error.

Comment: @ВалераГорбунов: I don't follow.  Your original question was regarding input.txt.  That has nothing to do with NoClassDefFoundError.  If you're getting that error, then you have a completely unrelated issue (something to do with your classpath).

Comment: If that's correct than I am doing something completely wrong. Ignore this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Oli, I just wanted to let you know that the problem was indeed a classpath issue. I had to manual say

    set classpath=%classpath%;.;    

Basically issue with looking for local files.